# How can i store data in an array of object and display/read all of them at once in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I am making a project and I got a problem when I was taking data from the user using an array of objects.
When I run the program it asks for the data to be entered as many time as I want. But it only prints the data which user entered the first time.
**No, I cannot use lists, I can only use arrays. It's the demand of the problem**

```
using System;
namespace agentX
{
 class Application
  {
    private static int x;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of passengers");
        x=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Customer[] S = new Customer[x];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            S[i] = new Customer();
            S[i].SetInfo();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            S[j].printInfo();
        }

    }
 }
 class Customer
{
    //private data members
    private int rollno;
    private string name;
    private int age;

    //method to set student details
    public void SetInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name ");
        this.name=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the roll number");
        this.rollno = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the age");
        this.age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void printInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nStudent Record: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\tName     : " + this.name);
        Console.WriteLine("\tRollNo   : " + this.rollno);
        Console.WriteLine("\tAge      : " + this.age);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

[image: This is the output]

Comment: You have `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of your `printInfo()` method, so you need to press a key after each object has printed its info for the loop to continue.

Comment: I am feeling too dumb now, seconds after posting this question i pressed a button and .... 
I am sorry for wasting everyone's time

Comment: @TarunBisht Mistakes like this happen.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

From your `printInfo` method you want to move the last line `Console.ReadKey();` out to your `Main` under the last loop. Reason being is that `Console.ReadKey()` blocks the loop until you press a key.

```
public void printInfo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nStudent Record: ");
    Console.WriteLine("\tName     : " + this.name);
    Console.WriteLine("\tRollNo   : " + this.rollno);
    Console.WriteLine("\tAge      : " + this.age);

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of passengers");
    x=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Customer[] S = new Customer[x];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        S[i] = new Customer();
        S[i].SetInfo();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        S[j].printInfo();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```